# @font-face broken on external websites configured to use my domain

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, tumblr

I've been using @font-face on a tumblr blog since last year, and this tumblr blog is configured to use blog.mydomain.com. All assets such as css, font files, etc. are served from my hosting/domain to the blog.

My server has also been configured to permit hotlink access to my domain, blog.mydomain.com, and tumblr.com. I also have cross origin allowed for web font files.

It's been working perfectly on all browsers until just today all of a sudden. It isn't working in any browser except Firefox. In Chrome, Opera and others, the text just appears blank. Since it isn't falling back to sans-serif, it's like it thinks it's loaded, but it's just not actually rendering.

I've been using the following bulletproof @font-face all this time:

```
@font-face{font-family:"din";src:url("//mydomain.com/assets/css/din.eot?") format("embedded-opentype"), 
url("//mydomain.com/assets/css/din.woff") format("woff"), 
url("//mydomain.com/assets/css/din.ttf") format("truetype");font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}
@font-face {font-family:"din";src:url("//mydomain.com/assets/css/din-medium.eot?") format("embedded-opentype"), 
url("//mydomain.com/assets/css/din-medium.woff") format("woff"), 
url("//mydomain.com/assets/css/din-medium.ttf") format("truetype");font-weight:500;font-style:normal}
```

I just can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: I was earlier, but it wasn't something of mine. It was some temporary error from tumblr's forcefully inserted JavaScript. However, I just noticed now that if I click a photoset(which is embedded on tumblr through an iframe), the font suddenly renders, but if I go to another page, it disappears again.

Comment: Is this the same on all browsers, or more than one browser at least?

Comment: I believe the issues is CORS. You will need to either upload the fonts  + stylesheet directly to Tumblr or Base64 your `.ttf` and `.woff` files: http://echoes.justindickinson.com/post/4348775348/making-font-face-work-on-tumblr

Comment: I'll try Base64. I've used it once before and thought it was pretty interesting, but if it fixes this issue, I'll definitely try it again.

Comment: I played with it for a while, and it's now working flawlessly. Thank you.